# Getting a combobox list from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me to find the right code with path to get the column of my combobox.list of a userform from another workbook?

I am talking about the path because I want to get it even if the second workbook is closed :

The path of the second workbook is : `C:\Users\rameur\Desktop`

The name of the workbook: `Test.xlsm`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox1.List = ?????.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("Tableau1[Zones]").Value
end sub
```

Comment: `Me.ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("Tableau1[Zones]").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from a closed workbook involves more than just the name of the workbook. Ron de Bruin has a series of sample macros on his web site. He has written the GetData function to retrieve data from closed workbooks.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm